# Multithreade program consumer causes program to freeze

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I wrote multithreaded program and the producer works fine. I know this because I disable the consumer and the producers gives the expected output. The producer is designed to populate the shared buffer with random values 1 - 10 and the producers take turn filling the buffer. All the elements in the buffer are initially set to -1 indicating to the producers that they are empty. The producer is then supposed to signal the consumer that it has filled an element of the buffer and to come consume it. When I add in the consumer the program fills a few elements, consumes 1 and then freezes.

This is the output I receive with the consumer added in. The program signal once, produces for a few lines, then freezes. As I said when the consumer is not added in the producer works as expected. I have been working on this for awhile, and I can't figure this out. I am thinking the issue is with the consumer.

```
Producer thread 976 and value: 3
Producer thread 231312 and value: 3
Signal
Producer thread 976 and value: 3
Producer thread 231312 and value: 3
buff[1] = 3 and thread = 1232
Producer thread 976 and value: 2
Producer thread 231312 and value: 2
Producer thread 297568 and value: 3
Producer thread 298080 and value: 3
Producer thread 298592 and value: 3
```

For this type of program, how should the consumer look?

This is program

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    #define THREADS 5
    #define ELEMENTS 120



    int value = 0;
    int saveValue = 0;
    void *produce(void *arg);
    void *consume(void *arg);
    int producerCount =0;
    int consumerCount = ELEMENTS;

    struct {
      pthread_mutex_t mutex;
      int index;
      int value; 
      int MyShBuff[ELEMENTS];
    } add = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, 0, 0}; 


      struct{
       pthread_mutex_t    mutex;
       pthread_cond_t     cond;
       int nready;
       int value;
       int empty;
       int counter;

       /* number ready for consumer */
    } nready = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,0, -2, ELEMENTS};

    int main()
    {
        pthread_t tid_producer[THREADS], tid_consumer[THREADS];
        int i, j, k;

        //Ready buffer for producers
        for (i =0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
        {
            add.MyShBuff[i]=-1;
        }



        for(j = 0; j < THREADS; j++) {

       pthread_create(&tid_producer[j], NULL, &produce, NULL);
       pthread_create(&tid_consumer[j], NULL, &consume, NULL);
    }



     /* wait for all producers and the consumer*/

        for(k = 0; k < THREADS; k++) {
            pthread_join(tid_producer[k], NULL);
            pthread_join(tid_consumer[k], NULL);    
        }


        exit(0);    
        return 0;
    }

    void *produce(void *arg)
    { 
    int i = 0;


    for ( ; ; ) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&add.mutex);
        if(add.index  >= ELEMENTS)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        if(add.MyShBuff[add.index] == -1)
        {
         add.value = rand() % 10 + 0;   
         add.MyShBuff[add.index] = add.value;
         printf("Producer thread %d and value: %d\n" ,pthread_self(), add.MyShBuff[add.index]);
         add.index++;
        }
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
         if(nready.nready == 0)
         {
         pthread_cond_signal(&nready.cond);
         printf("Signal\n");
         }

        nready.nready++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

        }


    }


    void *consume(void *arg)
    {
     int i;

      while(nready.empty != 0)
      {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
        while (nready.nready == 0)
        {
           pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond,&nready.mutex);
            nready.nready--;
             nready.empty--;
             nready.counter++;
             pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&add.mutex);
             printf("buff[%d] = %d and thread = %d\n", nready.counter, add.MyShBuff[nready.counter], pthread_self());
             add.MyShBuff[nready.counter] = -2;
             pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);



        }

      }

            return NULL;

    }
```

I think I made the suggested changes. This is the program with the edits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define THREADS 5
#define ELEMENTS 120



int value = 0;
int saveValue = 0;
void *produce(void *arg);
void *consume(void *arg);
int producerCount =0;
int consumerCount = ELEMENTS;

struct {
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  int index;
  int value; 
  int MyShBuff[ELEMENTS];
} add = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, 0, 0}; 


  struct{
   pthread_mutex_t    mutex;
   pthread_cond_t     cond;
   int nready;
   int value;
   int empty;
   int counter;

   /* number ready for consumer */
} nready = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,0, -2, ELEMENTS};

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid_producer[THREADS], tid_consumer[THREADS];
    int i, j, k;

    //Ready buffer for producers
    for (i =0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        add.MyShBuff[i]=-1;
    }



    for(j = 0; j < THREADS; j++) {

   pthread_create(&tid_producer[j], NULL, &produce, NULL);
   pthread_create(&tid_consumer[j], NULL, &consume, NULL);
}



 /* wait for all producers and the consumer*/

    for(k = 0; k < THREADS; k++) {
        pthread_join(tid_producer[k], NULL);
        pthread_join(tid_consumer[k], NULL);    
    }

     /* Clean up and exit */

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&nready.mutex);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&add.mutex);
   pthread_cond_destroy(&nready.cond);
   pthread_exit(NULL);

    exit(0);    
    return 0;
}

 void *produce(void *arg)
    { 
    int i = 0;


    for ( ; ; ) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&add.mutex);
        if(add.index  >= ELEMENTS)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        if(add.MyShBuff[add.index] == -1)
        {
         add.value = rand() % 10 + 0;   
         add.MyShBuff[add.index] = add.value;
         printf("Producer thread %d and value: %d\n" ,pthread_self(), add.MyShBuff[add.index]);
         add.index++;
        }
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
         if(nready.nready == 0)
         {
         pthread_cond_broadcast(&nready.cond);
         printf("Signal\n");
         }

        nready.nready++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

        }


    }


void *consume(void *arg)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);

  while(nready.empty != 0)
  {

    while (nready.nready == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond,&nready.mutex);

         nready.nready--;
         nready.empty--;

         pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&add.mutex);
         printf("buff[%d] = %d and thread = %d\n", nready.counter, add.MyShBuff[nready.counter], pthread_self());
         add.MyShBuff[nready.counter] = -2;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
        nready.counter++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

    }
  }


        return NULL;

}
```

2nd edit of the consumer().

```
void *consume(void *arg)
{

pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);

  while(nready.empty != 0)
  {

    while (nready.nready == 0)
    {


        pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond,&nready.mutex);


         pthread_mutex_lock(&add.mutex);
         printf("buff[%d] = %d and thread = %d\n", nready.counter, add.MyShBuff[nready.counter], pthread_self());
         add.MyShBuff[nready.counter] = -2;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&add.mutex);

        nready.counter++;   
        nready.empty--;
        printf("Empty %d\n" , nready.empty);

    }

    nready.nready--;

  }


  return NULL;


}
```

Comment: do not lock the mutex before signalling. make sure it is unlocked.

Comment: No, @Serge, not only is it not a problem to have the associated mutex locked when you signal the CV, but it's common and often useful.

Comment: Any other suggestions as to what might be causing my program to lock up?

Answer (score 2):

Your `consume()` function has at least four problems with its use of shared variables and synchronization objects:

1. In the outer `while` condition, it reads shared variable `nready.empty` outside the protection of any mutex (or semaphore).  Elsewhere, the value of that variable is modified.  As a result, your program's behavior is undefined.
2. It locks mutex `nready.mutex` *outside* the inner loop, but unlocks it *inside* (and does not re-lock it).  Thus, if the inner loop iterates more than once on a given iteration of the outer loop -- which it very plausibly might do -- then

   - On the second and subsequent iterations, the function attempts to access and possibly modify other members of the shared `nready` structure without protection of a mutex.
   - On the second and subsequent iterations, the function attempts to wait on condition variable `nready.cond` without having locked the mutex you specify for that purpose (`nready.mutex`)
   - On the second and subsequent iterations, the function attempts to unlock a mutex that it does not have locked.
3. It appears to assume that in aggregate over all threads, it will receive exactly one signal for each one sent via the condition variable.  That is not a safe assumption, because

   - signals are not queued.  If a producer thread sends a signal when no consumer is waiting then that signal will be lost.  Furthermore,
   - spurious wakeups can happen, in which a thread returns from `pthread_cond_wait()` without a corresponding call having been  made to `pthread_cond_signal()`.  Those are unusual, but they do occur, and you need to be prepared for them.
4. You have no provision for shutting down consumer threads when there is no more work to perform.  The one that actually processes the last unit of work probably will exit, but all the others will probably be stuck, waiting indefinitely on the condition variable.

---

Condition variables are so named because they are designed around the concept of permitting threads to suspend operation until some condition becomes true.  The conventional usage paradigm for waiting on a condition variable is as follows:

1. Lock the associated mutex.
2. Optionally, perform some work.
3. Check the CV's associated condition.  Accesses to any shared variables on which the condition is based must everywhere be protected by the same mutex used with the CV.
4. If the condition is satisfied, then proceed without waiting (skip to step 6); otherwise start waiting on the CV
5. Upon returning from the wait, **go back to step 3**.  It is essential to re-check the condition to ensure that it is true, lest it have been made false again by some other thread or never have been true in the first place.
6. Optionally, perform some work.
7. Unlock the mutex.

Having implemented that as described, you may also find that you can benefit from relying on `pthread_cond_broadcast()` instead of `pthread_cond_signal()`.  In particular, that could form part -- but not all -- of an approach to resolving the consumer shutdown problem.

Comment: How do I shut down the consumer threads? Should I add in pthread_exit() into the consumer?

Comment: The problem is not how to effect the actual thread termination itself, @Rubiks.  You could indeed call `pthread_exit()`, but each consumer thread will also shutdown naturally when the `consumer()` function returns.  You seem to be counting on the latter, which is fine.  The problem is making sure that every thread will actually do one of those things when the producers have finished producing and there is nothing left to consume.

Comment: I think I made the changes you suggested, but it still freezes. I posted underneath the old code, the new code with the edits. I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: At first glance, you are still unlocking mutex `nready.mutex` inside the inner loop, such that it will not be locked at the beginning of a second iteration of that loop.  Additionally, no, it doesn't look like you implemented the model for condition variable usage that I described.

Comment: A specific consequence of those particular problems is that your `consumer()` can fairly easily get stuck spinning: suppose that when it returns from waiting on the condition variable, `nready.nready` and `nready.empty` both have values greater than 1.  Each will be decremented in the inner loop, after which the outer loop's condition will still be satisfied, but the inner one's won't.  The outer loop may then spin indefinitely, always skipping the inner loop, quite possibly not seeing modifications to those shared variables on account of not locking the mutex.

Comment: I think I incorporated the edits that were suggested. The program mostly works. It runs almost through all 120 elements producing and consuming. When it gets to the last 5 elements it locks up. I just posted the newly edited consume() and would appreciate your advice

Comment: @Rubiks, your new `consume()` function now successfully protects all access to `nready` via its mutex -- good.  It does so by never unlocking it (except implicitly while waiting on the CV) -- bad.  The revised code *still* fails to check the CV's associated condition before waiting and after waking from a wait.  Moreover, if the new `consume()` wakes from waiting on the CV to find multiple items ready (`nready.nready > 1`) then it consumes only one of them (one `printf` call) and discards the rest.

Comment: Hmm -- I seem to have overstated my case slightly.  You do now successfully test the CV condition before waiting, but you still do not re-check it after waking.  To implement that correctly, you probably need to structure your loops differently, and that probably will lead you in a direction that helps with the other issues, too.

Comment: Im not quite what you mean. I tried to put in an if statement after the wait() to check the condition again, but it still locks up. Not sure I will ever figure this one out

Comment: I'm inclined to suspect that you're trying to tackle too many new concepts at the same time.  I suggest you take a step back, and start from scratch with a simpler problem: only one producer and one consumer.  Then expand to multiple consumers, and finally add in multiple producers.  Be sure from the beginning to build in the CV usage paradigm I presented to you, because you seem to be having trouble seeing how to retrofit your current code to implement it.